# How to increase the UIButton Image size in Swift3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, xcode8

I am using the default `UIImage` property of the `UIButton` to set the back image . I have successfully done it but it seems that the `image` is appearing small. How to increase the size of the image in `UIButton`?

```
    let viewForNavigation = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 40))
    viewForNavigation.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let backbutton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 8, width: 320, height: 20))
    backbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "back_button"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    backbutton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right:10)
    backbutton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    backbutton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    backbutton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont().robotoMedium(withFontSize: 20)
    backbutton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)

    backbutton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: UIControlState.normal)
    backbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(exitViewController), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    viewForNavigation.addSubview(backbutton)
    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: viewForNavigation)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

[image: Please see the image. I need to increase the image size]

Comment: instead of setImage you can use setBackground Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have choose wrong size back button image, please use below image for back button:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) @Chelsea Shawra